# Getting/setting the widths of columns in a table (PyGTK)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

I have several Tables in a PyGTK display whose rows and columns I would like to align with each other. Is there a way to get and set the column dimensions in a Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GtkSizeGroup`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSizeGroup.html) to make like widgets in different tables request the same height and/or width.